# Assign each item of a range to each item of another range in a hash

Tags: ruby

I want to make a hash with two ranges.

So `(1..26)` is the first range, and `("A".."Z")` is the second. So `1 => "A", 2 => "B", 3 => "C"`, etc.

It would be nice to not have to make the hash manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h)

```
(1..26).zip('A'..'Z').to_h
 => {1=>"A", 2=>"B", 3=>"C", 4=>"D", 5=>"E", 6=>"F", 7=>"G", 8=>"H", 9=>"I", 10=>"J", 11=>"K", 12=>"L", 13=>"M", 14=>"N", 15=>"O", 16=>"P", 17=>"Q", 18=>"R", 19=>"S", 20=>"T", 21=>"U", 22=>"V", 23=>"W", 24=>"X", 25=>"Y", 26=>"Z"}
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that this is [Enumerable#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip), as readers may be more familiar with [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-zip). It's curious that the doc for `Enumerable#zip` does not mention that the argument can be a range (but this answer works). Am I missing something?

Comment: You're right. As you said this should use the zip from enumerable. Is that possible that the argument could be an enumerable too? Range is an enumerable

Comment: The same is true for `Array#zip`: `[1,2,3].zip('a'..'c') #=> [[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]]`. Try it with an enumerator: `e = (4..6).each #=> #<Enumerator: 4..6:each>; (1..3).zip(e) #=> [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]`!